# Azure SQL Server Firewall rules - using public IP, how to connect with mobile devices like laptops?

Tags: sql-server, azure, firewall

Mobile devices like laptops try to connect through different public IP addresses per day, so it is not pretty handy to create SQL Server firewall rules for them with public IPs.

What is the best way to connect with mobile devices to my Azure SQL Server? I found a lot of ideas online but non for now seems to be secure and easy to use at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VPN would probably be the answer if you're annoyed by having to go to the portal to add your IP.

I take it this question is purely for development, since your end-product wouldn't connect directly.

Comment: Yes it is for development, or more learning at the moment! How would you connect a end-product? Do you have any good ressources for learning all that? And thank you btw!

Answer (score 0):

an alternative would be to have a script that does add your current external IP to the firewall exclusions, you can use something like this:

```
$ip = ((iwr httpbin.org/ip -UseBasicParsing).content | convertfrom-json).origin
Set-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName rg1 -ServerName svc1 -FirewallRuleName rule1 -StartIpAddress $ip -EndIpAddress $ip
```

you have to precreate the rule first (or just use new-azsqlfirewallrule to create a new rule everytime).

Comment: Only problem with this approach is that there can be a maximum of 128 Firewall rules (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure) so someone needs to do constantly delete the firewall rules so that this quota is not exceeded.

Comment: well, thats why I'm just updating the same rule in the initial proposition :)

Comment: Oh...So basically try to create a new rule every time and if it fails then try to set the firewall rule (or the other way round). Right?

Comment: well, that might be a way around that, but I was actually just thinking of updating the same rule (since the question implies usage for a single person, so a person would be only updating his own firewall rule).

Comment: I see. I saw the word "devices" in OP so I thought there might be many users :).